# MapBox React Native Navigation Tracking

Tags: react-native, navigation, maps, mapbox

How do you implement a navigation tracking in real time with mapbox in react-native?

I'm looking into the docs and this polyline looks kinda like it but im not sure. I can display a map with user location from the quick start, but I'm not too sure how to use this component (Fairly new to React-Native).

Thanks!